# Name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
NameError: name 'Report_query' is not defined
```

И все было бы ясно, если бы я не объявил ее как глобальную, но я это сделал в функции

```
class ExcelReportsManager:

    Report_query = Queue()

    @staticmethod
    def get_storages_report(city_id, employee_id):
        res = []
        storages = Storage.query.filter(Storage.deleted.is_(False)).all() if not city_id else \
        Storage.query.filter(and_(Storage.deleted.is_(False), Storage.city_id == city_id)).all()
        for storage in storages:
            free_space = 0
            filled_num = 0
            for cell in storage.cells:
                filled_num += cell.filled
                free_space += cell.capacity - cell.filled
            storage_info = {'Город': storage.city.city,
                            'Склад': storage.name,
                            'Адрес склада': storage.address,
                            'Свободно': free_space,
                            'Занято': filled_num
                            }
            res.append(storage_info)
        ordered_list = ['Город', 'Склад', 'Адрес склада', 'Свободно', 'Занято']
        global Report_query
        Report_query.put(ExcelReportsManager.__generate_xlsx(ordered_list, res, employee_id))
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: почитайте хотя бы [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/faq.html):

Comment: `global` работает совсем не так как вы думаете. Пространство имён класса это не глобальное пространство имён

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `Report_query` - не просто переменная, а атрибут класса. Декоратор `@staticmethod` говорит о том, что `get_storages_report()` этому классу не принадлежит, эта функция не "видит" объект, внутри которого он объявлен, следовательно, не видит и его атрибуты.

Заработает, если вы напишете

```
global ExcelReportsManager
ExcelReportsManager.Report_query.put(ExcelReportsManager.__generate_xlsx(ordered_list, res, employee_id))
```

но в итоге получается какая-то странная конструкция, думаю, вам нужно что-то поменять в архитектуре.

Comment: `global ExcelReportsManager` не нужно. А так да, заработало, спасибо.
Хоть и не вижу ничего странного в этой конструкции (если не использовать `global ExcelReportsManager`, конечно)

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов, я бы еще поменял `@staticmethod` на `@classmethod`, т.к. по факту метод работает с полями класса. Тогда нужно будет добавить `cls` первым аргументом метода, и можно будет обращаться к `Report_query` через `cls.Report_query`.

Comment: @insolor помимо всего прочего я обращаюсь к методам через api (проект весь через flask работает), поэтому не получится так настроить.